# Keras neural network not fitting in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I made a neural network in R using the Keras package. I basically made the same model I had created in python. I used the same data as well in the same order. However, when I run it in R, the model doesn't seem to be fitting at all.

When I call predict on the model, it returns the same value regardless of the input.

I'm guessing the weights are zeroing out and its returning the bias.

Heres how I built the model:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()

model %>%
layer_dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu',input=     c(18)) %>%
layer_dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu')%>%
layer_dropout(rate = 0.25) %>% 
layer_dense(units = 32, activation = 'relu') %>%
layer_dropout(rate = 0.25) %>% 
layer_dense(units = 16, activation = 'relu') %>%
layer_dropout(rate = 0.25) %>% 
layer_dense(units = 8, activation = 'relu') %>%
layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'softmax')
```

Heres the output when I call predict:

```
model%>%
    predict(nbainput_test_x)
```

Comment: Your first layer includes the argument `input = c(18)` . It does not appear that `layer_dense` has any argument called input.  Did you mean input_shape ?

Comment: yes sorry. It was input_shape. However, the model still doesn't. seem to fit the data.